# set css object-position property programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, object-fit

I am using the object-fit and object-position css properties to control the placement of an image in css. I want to programmatically set that position with javascript. I tried:

```
const panPos = 50;
document.querySelector('.image').style.objectPosition = `${panPos}% 0%`;
```

and nothing happens.

I can console log element.style and I see an objectPosition property, but setting it seems to have no effect.

Please note I am not talking about the `position` property (absolute, relative, etc).

I can also set this property with jquery using:

```
$('.image').css({
      'object-position': `${panPos}% 50%`  
    });
```

but I want to avoid jQuery. Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried using `document.querySelector('.image')[0]`? Also if you want this to function for multiple elements then you will need to iterate through the node collection and maybe using `document.querySelectorAll('.image')` would be better for multiple elements.

Comment: can you provide an example of what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set `object-fit` to `none` as well. They are used together, otherwise, `object-position` gets ignored. So:

```
const panPos = 50;
document.querySelector('.image').style.objectFit = 'none';
document.querySelector('.image').style.objectPosition = `${panPos}% 0%`;
```

For more info, refer to:

- https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-position/
- https://codepen.io/robinrendle/pen/raGOOJ